# postgreSQL nested query performing slow

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

I have these three tables:

1. create table words (id integer, word text, freq integer);
2. create table sentences (id integer, sentence text);
3. create table index (wordId integer, sentenceId integer, position integer);

Index is a inverted index and denotes which word occurs in which sentence. Furthermoore I have an index on id from the table words and sentences.

This query determines in which sentences a given word occurs and returns the first match:

```
select S.sentence from sentences S, words W, index I
where W.word = '#erhoehungen' and W.id = I.wordId and S.id = I.sentenceId
limit 1;
```

But when I want to retrieve a sentence where two words occur together like:

```
select S.sentence from sentences S, words W, index I
where W.word = '#dreikampf' and I.wordId = W.id and S.id = I.sentenceId and
S.id in (
    select S.id from sentences S, words W, index I
    where W.word = 'bruederle' and W.id = I.wordId and S.id = I.sentenceId
)
limit 1;
```

This query is much slower. Is there any trick to speed it up? Following things I did so far:

- increased shared_buffer to 32MB
- increased work_mem to 15MB
- ran analyze on all tables
- as mentioned created index on words id and sentences id

Regards.

€Dit:

Here is the output of the explain analyze query statement: http://pastebin.com/t2M5w4na

These three create statements are actually my original create statements. Should I add primary key to the tables sentences and words and reference these as foreign keys in the index? But what primary key should I use for the index table? SentId and wordId together are not unique and even if I add pos which denotes the position of the word in the sentence it is not unique.

updated to:

1. create table words (id integer, word text, freq integer, primary key(id));
2. create table sentences (id integer, sentence text, primary key(id));
3. create table index (wordId integer, sentenceId integer, position integer, foreign key(wordId) references words(id), foreign key(sentenceId) references sentences(sentenceId));

Comment: Edit your question, and paste the output of `explain analyze your_query`, where "your_query" represents your troublesome SELECT statement. Also, actual CREATE TABLE statements can help a lot.

Comment: Your table `index` (terrible name, BTW) needs at least a primary key. `{sentenceid, position}` is the obvious choice. Having one or two compound indexes on `{sentenceid,wordid}` and/or `{wordid,sentenceid}` would probably help, too.

Comment: Plus: you will need a UNIQUE constraint or index for the _natural_ key of the words table: the `word` itself. off-record: RDBMS and nlp are a bad match. You could take a look at other storage methods (for Postgres: hstore, or GIST indexes for full-text search)

Comment: The key value pair {sentenceid, position} is not unique, because some sentences are duplicated. Thanks for the information about the other storage methods.

Comment: Why would you want to allow a duplicate sentence? Without extra (key) columns, a duplicate sentence is meaningless.

Comment: Sentences are tweets and you can reweet them. So duplicates are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should be more efficient:

```
SELECT s.id, s.sentence FROM words w
JOIN INDEX i ON w.id = i.wordId
JOIN sentences s ON i.sentenceId = s.id
WHERE w.word IN ('#dreikampf', 'bruederle')
GROUP BY s.id, s.sentence
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Just make sure the amount of items in the `IN` clause matches the amount of items in the `HAVING` clause.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fb73c/1).

Comment: Also you don't need to add more SQL code in this solution if you want to add more words but rather change the parameters :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's much faster than my solution, but still in seconds range. Maybe it's because of the size of the tables: words(255715 rows), sentences(5085623 rows) and index(61029790 rows).

Comment: 61 MM? That's big number :) The next level of performance would be working on indexes I guess. But probably you should ask that question in [dba.se].

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe I could also try mysql with MyISAM as storage engine, because it uses less security stuff than postgreSQL - But I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have indexes on columns `wordId`, `sentenceId`. Please create them and query will work much faster.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_index_wordId ON index USING btree (wordId);
CREATE INDEX idx_index_sentenceId ON index USING btree (sentenceId);
```

Using reserved word `index` as table name is not a good idea – you may need to escape it in some cases.
Probably you should also add column `id` to `index` table and make it primary key.

Please use [Mosty Mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho) query and show it's `explain analyze` output after you make indexes. May be it can work even faster.

Update:

please try new query:

```
select S.sentence from sentences S where S.id in
(select sentenceId from index I where 
I.wordId in (select id from words where word IN ('#dreikampf', 'bruederle'))
group by I.sentenceId
having count(distinct I.wordId) = 2
limit 1)
```

Comment: added index to both id's and renamed the index table to inv_w. Here is the output of explain analyze: pastebin.com/veVds6KP Still in seconds range. I'm only interested in the first / one match, so maybe I can use a cursor? Because this query retrieves all solutions.

Comment: Please also create this index:
`CREATE INDEX idx_words_word ON words USING btree (word);`

and add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query for fetching only one row.

Comment: I also updated my answer – please try new query. It should work faster and more correctly (handle cases when 2 identical words are in one sentence).

Comment: The query with "#dreikampf' and 'bruederle' needs ~ 900 ms. But with the words 'bruederle' and 'punto-vergleich' it takes 12629 ms :/

Comment: Please create one more index `CREATE INDEX idx_index_wordId_sentenceId ON index USING btree (wordId, sentenceId);`. For some reason Postgres chosen bad plan, this should help.